# How do I control the state of this child component upon a button click in its parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to structure two React components on a site that I'm building.

I have a "book-review" component that should display a respective modal (by adding the "is-active" class to `<div className="modal" />`) when a review is clicked. For simplicity's sake, let's say that on this page there's a button with an `onClick` that opens a single modal. The background of this modal takes up the whole screen, so when the background of the modal is clicked, the modal should close.

Closing the modal is easy enough – I just bind the `_closeModal` function to the modal background. But how do I open a modal from within the book review?

**modal.js**:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`modal ${this.state.modalOpen ? "is-active" : ""}`}>
        <div className="modal-background" onClick={this._closeModal}>
      ...
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  _closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false,
    })
  }
}
```

**book-review.js**:

```
class BookReview extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal />
        <button onClick={/* open the modal */}>Open Modal</button>
      ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I feel that I should control modal state from within its own component, not the book review. The book review will already have a state object with lots of information, so my intuition says that it will get very messy to track all of the modal states as well.

In other threads, people have said that you shouldn't try to control child state from a parent component. The main problem is that I need `_closeModal` to be inside the child component (because the modal background takes up the whole screen) and `_openModal` to be inside the parent component (because the modal won't even be visible until this function is called). Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to keep the logic of opening and closing of modal in the parent component. So the BookReview component has full control of it. Modal only know that if a prop is set to true the it should display the Modal. here is modified solution:

```
import React from 'react';

class Modal extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`modal ${this.props.isOpen ? "is-active" : ""}`}>
                <div className="modal-background" onClick={this.props.closeModal}>
                    this is a modal
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class BookReview extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen:false
        };
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    }

    openModal(){
        this.setState({isOpen: true});
        console.log('modal opened');

    }

    closeModal(){
        this.setState({isOpen:false});
        console.log('modal closed');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} closeModal={this.closeModal}/>
                <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open Modal</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default BookReview;
```

I also assume that there would be a parent component rendering list of BookReview. So you can pass a bookId prop in BookReview, and use the BookReview parent to control which BookReview's modal is being displayed.

Comment: THANK YOU, oh my goodness. It all seems so clear to me now! I really appreciate it. Oh and by the way, this is using GatsbyJS, so BookReview is actually a page (works the same as a component though). It will have a list of <BookReviewEntry />s.

Answer (score 2):

You should have `state` to open modal in `BookReview` component, and pass it to child component as `props`

```
class BookReview extends React.Component {
  state={modalOpen: false}

  _openModal = () => {
     this.setState({modalOpen:true})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalOpen}/>
        <button onClick={this._openModal}>Open Modal</button>
      ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In child component, you should use `props` from parent to open modal, and `componentDidUpdate` for subsequent `props` change.

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalOpen: props.isOpen,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {   //This will take care of props change from parent
   if (prevProps.isOpen !== this.props.isOpen) {
     this.setState({modalOpen:this.props.isOpen},()=>console.log(this.state.modalOpen))
   }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`modal ${this.state.modalOpen ? "is-active" : ""}`}>
        <div className="modal-background" onClick={this._closeModal}>
      ...
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  _closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to get this to work – it's close, but the problem is that once BookReview's state changes for the first time, it will remain as true from there on out. Once you open the modal and close it for the first time, you can no longer open it again.

Comment: This answer is based on your requirement - *In other threads, people have said that you shouldn't try to control child state from a parent component. The main problem is that I need _closeModal to be inside the child component (because the modal background takes up the whole screen) and _openModal to be inside the parent component (because the modal won't even be visible until this function is called).*

Comment: This is the issue when you control element from multiple places, you should always have control at one place only.

Comment: Sorry about that, and I appreciate you trying to fit the answer into my spec. I was vastly overlooking passing the `_closeModal` function as a prop. I haven't written a ton of React code in my life yet, so I'm still getting a feel for the design patterns. I should have phrased the question as "how can I do this better" rather than "how do I do it like this"?

Answer (score 0):

in Modal component add a method to open modal

```
openModal(){
    // set modal open
}
```

in Book review component:

```
<modal ref="modal" />
<button onClick={() => this.refs.modal.openModal()}>Click</button>
```

Comment: Do you think it will work for functional component?

Comment: Yes, Do you think not?

Comment: I tried and it is not working with functional componet, give it a try. If it works then update the answer it will helpful for others.